# refs vs onChange

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I've recently started learning react.js (loving it!) and ran into an interesting scenario with handling input values.

In the egghead tutorial they had you update an input using a `ref` like so:

```
handleSubmit(){
    var newNote = this.refs.note.value;
    this.refs.note.value = '';
    this.props.addNote(newNote);
}

<input type="text"  ref="note" />
<button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}> 
  Submit 
</button>
```

Later, I was playing with the [material ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) library (also awesome) and ran into a problem where I couldn't update one of the material components (Probably because of [this](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1030) issue) using a `ref`. After some time on Google I found that you could use a the `state`, and just update it using an `onChange` function, like so:

```
handleNoteChange(e){
    this.setState({newNote: e.target.value});
}

<TextField 
    type="text" 
    value={this.state.newNote} 
    onChange={this.handleNoteChange.bind(this)} />
```

It seems like using a `ref` would be easier, however, in my recent time learning react native, everything you do seems to be the second way, using an `onChange` function and a `state` variable.

So my question is, moving forward, would it be better to use one over the other? Maybe there are limitations which make using the `state` better on native?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In React, avoid manipulating the DOM using references. You should never do anything like this:

```
this.refs.note.value = '';
```

It's fine to read from the DOM when necessary (usually in response to user input), but the only way information should pass from your application to the DOM is via your `render()` method. Otherwise, the DOM becomes out of sync with your application. In React, your "source of truth" lives in memory, not in the DOM.

The second example you provide is the standard React way. The view - as defined by the `render()` method - is ultimately derived from `props` and `state`. Changing the state triggers a change in view. So calling `this.setState()` will force your component to re-render.

Comment: Additionally I will look at using a more 'fluxy' way of handling data. Keep the data in a store, and update components when the store updates.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation while doing a Pluralsight tutorial on react.  I thought I would share my experience and add another example as well. The tutorial altered the value of in input via it's ref value.

`ReactDOM.findDOMNode(...)`

Using ref shortens the code, but also alters the input value directly instead or relying on component state.

```
var Form = React.createClass({
  onSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var loginInput = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.login);
    this.props.addCard(loginInput.value);
    loginInput.value = '';
  },
  render: function(){
    return (<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <input placeholder="login" ref="login"/>
      <button>Add</button>
    </form>);
  }
});
```

I modified the code to access and modify the input value via state.

```
var Form = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {inputLogin: ''}
  },
  onKeyUpHandler: function(e){
    this.setState({inputLogin: e.target.value})
  },
  onSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.addCard(this.state.inputLogin);
    this.setState({inputLogin: ''})
  },
  render: function(){
    return (<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <input placeholder="login" onKeyUp={this.onKeyUpHandler}/>
      <button>Add</button>
    </form>);
  }
});
```

It's a little more verbose but now its using state properly.